# Listen to URL location firefox extension

Tags: firefox, pdf, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to detect when the user changes to a PDF page, for example: [w4 Form](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf). I know how to get the URL of the current page by either using `document.location.href` or `document.URL`. They both work fine, however when a PDF page is loaded those calls do not work.

I am inserting a content script through `page-mod`. The code is the following:

```js
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptWhen: 'start',
    contentScript: 'console.log(document.location.href);'
});
```

So I am guessing that you cannot insert a content script into a PDF page. What alternatives do I have to detect when a user is inside a PDF page?

In Chrome I am able to do this by assigning a background page. Is there a similar way to do this with the Add-on SDK? I looked at `page-worker` but I couldn't find anything there either since it is just an invisible page and not a background page.

Comment: This also does not work:  
  
`code
tabs.activeTab.on('ready', function(tab) {  
  console.log('LOADED URL: " +  tab.url)  
});`

Comment: What do you mean by "PDF page is loaded"? Do you mean that Adobe Reader displays the PDF in the browser? Or do you generally want to detect that the user clicks a PDF link?

Comment: @WladimirPalant
What I mean is that I want to know when the user viewing a PDF page in their browser. So yes, when the browser is displaying a PDF page. I can do this in Chrome by just checking the URL of the current page and checking the last 4 characters to see if it equals to ".pdf", however, I cannot do this in Firefox for some reason. How would I detect if the user clicked a PDF link?

Comment: Firefox isn't capable of displaying PDF files which is why I am asking. It is normally the Adobe Reader plugin doing that. Or Foxit Reader. Or none - in my browser PDF files trigger a download prompt.

Comment: True. So I guess since the Firefox is not reading the PDF there is no way to access the URL of the PDF file? Is there any way to track when a user is being redirected to a PDF page?

Comment: Could you do something with binding to click events on links and reacting to the user clicking on a PDF link *before* the PDF is loaded?